# How can I transcend my confusion over CSS?

Tags: css, resources

I am interested in improving my understanding of CSS.  I have been making web pages for a while, but I am still constantly thwarted by bizarre behavior that I can't explain when I try to get things to look the way I want.  I have a good bit of development experience and I have no trouble understanding the finer points of Javascript, PHP, or even C.  But when it comes to CSS and HTML, I find I am always trying to "trick" my code into working.

This must betray a lack of understanding on my part about how web pages and CSS actually work.  Are there any good books or resources I could look at toward the end of truly understanding what is going on under the hood?  I always feel like I'm at a loss, but I suspect I could get over that if I just cracked down and did some good reading.

Comment: I recommend [HTMLDog](http://www.htmldog.com/). Also, [these videos](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/) from Google are helpful.

Comment: Understanding something as a whole comes from understanding all the parts that compose it - if you have a specific question about CSS, you can ask it and get a specific answer.  Otherwise, you may as well just go to a bookstore and get the thickest book you can find on CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I find I am always trying to "trick" my code into working.

Yep. CSS is often about creating the illusion of the effect you intend, rather than actually doing what you intend.

That said, there are very specific rules, as [specified by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/). Understanding the [visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html) can do wonders for your understanding as well. These specs are dense, and often confusing, however, so figuring out specific properties and building knowledge step by step is often the easier way to go. Find tutorials (see links below), or just play with them and see what happens (that's how I learned `float` and `clear`).

Even though it's often dead, there are a few SO users who will check the [CSS Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3840/css) regularly (myself included), so if you have general questions (inappropriate for an actual SO question), feel free to ask there, and someone will eventually ping you back.

Also, I've created a [Useful CSS Links](https://gist.github.com/1356350) document with links to official documents, several tutorials, and other CSS resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  I do think a lot of my confusion is centered around the way that HTML documents have a flow.  I'll check out all those links.

Comment: No problem! A lot of people have trouble with document flow, but it's pretty fun to work with when you get used to it.

Comment: There's also some good stuff on the [CSS Tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info) (including some things I don't personally agree with, like Resets and pre-processors, but you should probably develop your own opinion on those)

Comment: @RyanKinal: Thanks, you rock! I was looking for something exactly like CSSLint and you pointed me to it, +1.

Answer (score 3):

You might be getting mesmerized by the pretty blinking lights and forgetting to watch how everything is connected together. Just like you can get too focused on how a node in the DOM is affected by your javascript, you can't forget about the parents and siblings and how they all fit together. Your biggest problems are probably positioning. Remember how all the elements are connected together and that will solve a lot of confusion.

Comment: Indeed! Document flow is *very important*

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've already been here, but just in case:

Learn CSS:
http://w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Learn CSS3: 
http://w3schools.com/css3/default.asp

However, the best way to learn this stuff is by trial-and-error. HTML and CSS are unique in their forgiving approach to malformation/errors. This, along with the fact that no two browsers render HTML/CSS exactly alike, presents a certain ambiguity that even experienced HTML/CSS developers occasionally grapple with.

Still, learning this stuff is a blast, and really rewarding once you get a handle on it. Happy coding!

Comment: @thirtydot To be fair, w3schools has been updating its content. I've actually been reading through their CSS tutorials, and so far they're pretty accurate. In general, w3schools isn't recommended, but it has gotten better.

Comment: Admittedly, it's far from perfect, but features like the TryIt! editor provide an enhanced level of 'quick-and-dirty' interactive learning where many other tutorials do not.